# Angular Accordion not resolving to correct html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use Angular Accordion with ng-repeat. I am facing a strange behavior where the html is not resolved properly on my page and my accordion does not work at all. But the same code works like charm on plunkr.

Please refer to this plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/3Z450PxtGynDaTLh5zwl/

If I inspect element on the above plunkr, I get the html body like this

```html
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl" class="ng-scope">
   <accordion>
      <div class="accordion" ng-transclude="">
         <!-- ngRepeat: group in groups -->
         <div class="accordion-group ng-scope" heading="Title 1" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle ng-binding" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" accordion-transclude="heading">Title 1</a></div>
            <div class="accordion-body collapse" collapse="!isOpen" style="height: auto;">
               <div class="accordion-inner" ng-transclude="">
                  <ul class="ng-scope">
                     <!-- ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
                     <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-scope ng-binding">item 1</li>
                     <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-scope ng-binding">item 2</li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-group ng-scope" heading="Title 2" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle ng-binding" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" accordion-transclude="heading">Title 2</a></div>
            <div class="accordion-body collapse" collapse="!isOpen" style="height: 0px;">
               <div class="accordion-inner" ng-transclude="">
                  <ul class="ng-scope">
                     <!-- ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
                     <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-scope ng-binding">item 3</li>
                     <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-scope ng-binding">item 4</li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </accordion>
</div>
```

But when I run the exact same code on my web page, I get the html like this :

```html
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl" class="ng-scope">
   <accordion>
      <!-- ngRepeat: group in groups -->
      <accordion-group heading="Title 1" ng-repeat="group in groups" class="ng-scope">
         <ul>
            <!-- ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-binding ng-scope">item 1</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-binding ng-scope">item 2</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
         </ul>
      </accordion-group>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: group in groups -->
      <accordion-group heading="Title 2" ng-repeat="group in groups" class="ng-scope">
         <ul>
            <!-- ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-binding ng-scope">item 3</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" class="ng-binding ng-scope">item 4</li>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
         </ul>
      </accordion-group>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: group in groups -->
   </accordion>
</div>
```

If you notice closely, the working copy resolves the accordion properly in to correct html and css classes but the one on my page is not resolving it properly. I am going crazy to figure out what is happening and I have really no clue.

I have created the diffs online for comparison: https://www.diffchecker.com/rG70Forz

My bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.5.5",
"bootstrap": "3.3.4",
"angular-route": "^1.5.5",
"angular-touch": "^1.5.5",
"angular-animate": "^1.5.5",
"typed.js": "^1.1.1",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"angular-bootstrap": "^2.1.3",
"ui.bootstrap": "ui-bootstrap#^2.1.3",
"angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1"
},
```

my app.js

```
angular
.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMap',
    'underscore',
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
```

Can somebody please point out what I could be doing wrong ? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Chang bootstrap cdn URL once. It works for me. 
[bootstrap css cdn link](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css%22%3E)

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Title 1",
      items: [{"item-title": "item 1"}, {"item-title": "item 2"}]
    },
    {
      title: "Title 2",
      items: [{"item-title": "item 3"}, {"item-title": "item 4"}]
    }
  ];
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <!-- <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">


  <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in group.items">{{item['item-title']}}</li>
      </ul>
    </accordion-group>   
  </accordion>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still does not work. I have tried that in the past and I tried it again. Still no luck :(

Comment: Ohhh... It was perfectly works for me. I have verified on different browsers also. All dependencies from cdn , I have no clue why this problem occurring???

Comment: That is exactly my question. It works stand alone but it does not work with in my app. My plunker link is a working copy but when I add the same code to my app, it breaks. I am suspecting this to be scoping issue but not able to figure out how to fix it. Thanks for your help.